# Google Plus Api Exception at runtime

Tags: java, android, android-activity, google-plus, google-play-services

Hello guys I have a problem with logging in to google plus, when I click on login nothing happens.

I state that I imported APIs google , I turned on the APIs on the site.

```
 public class GooglePlusActivity extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;

    // Google client to communicate with Google
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private boolean mIntentInProgress;
    private boolean mSignInClicked;
    private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build())
        .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        googlePlusLogin();

    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    private void resolveSignInError() {
        if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                mIntentInProgress = true;
                mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                mIntentInProgress = false;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        if (!result.hasResolution()) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this,
                    0).show();
            return;
        }

        if (!mIntentInProgress) {
            // Store the ConnectionResult for later usage
            mConnectionResult = result;
            if (mSignInClicked) {
                googlePlusLogin();
                resolveSignInError();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            if (responseCode != RESULT_OK) {
                mSignInClicked = false;
            }

            mIntentInProgress = false;

            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    public void onResume()
     {
         super.onResume();
         finish();

     }
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        mSignInClicked = false;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        getProfileInformation();
    }


    private void getProfileInformation() {
        try {
            if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
                Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
                String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
                String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
                String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Benvenuto " + email + ":" + currentPerson, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    public void googlePlusLogin() {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {           
            mSignInClicked = true;
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }

    private void googlePlusLogout() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}
```

This is start Activity

```
            if(v.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button) {
            Intent plus = new Intent(this, GooglePlusActivity.class);
            startActivity(plus); 

        }
```

And this is logcat

```
    03-15 20:55:09.847: W/System.err(22572): java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient must be connected.
03-15 20:55:09.847: W/System.err(22572):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.jx.a(Unknown Source)
03-15 20:55:09.847: W/System.err(22572):    at com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus.a(Unknown Source)
03-15 20:55:09.847: W/System.err(22572):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.pc.getCurrentPerson(Unknown Source)
03-15 20:55:09.847: W/System.err(22572):    at it.activity.GooglePlusActivity.getProfileInformation(GooglePlusActivity.java:111)
03-15 20:55:09.847: W/System.err(22572):    at it.activity.GooglePlusActivity.onStart(GooglePlusActivity.java:37)
03-15 20:55:09.847: W/System.err(22572):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1220)
03-15 20:55:09.847: W/System.err(22572):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5993)
03-15 20:55:09.847: W/System.err(22572):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2268)
03-15 20:55:09.847: W/System.err(22572):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2367)
03-15 20:55:09.847: W/System.err(22572):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
03-15 20:55:09.847: W/System.err(22572):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
03-15 20:55:09.847: W/System.err(22572):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-15 20:55:09.847: W/System.err(22572):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
03-15 20:55:09.848: W/System.err(22572):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5274)
03-15 20:55:09.848: W/System.err(22572):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-15 20:55:09.848: W/System.err(22572):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
03-15 20:55:09.848: W/System.err(22572):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
03-15 20:55:09.848: W/System.err(22572):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
03-15 20:55:09.848: W/System.err(22572): java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient must be connected.
03-15 20:55:09.848: W/System.err(22572):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.jx.a(Unknown Source)
03-15 20:55:09.848: W/System.err(22572):    at com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus.a(Unknown Source)
03-15 20:55:09.848: W/System.err(22572):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.pc.getCurrentPerson(Unknown Source)
03-15 20:55:09.848: W/System.err(22572):    at it.activity.GooglePlusActivity.getProfileInformation(GooglePlusActivity.java:111)
03-15 20:55:09.848: W/System.err(22572):    at it.activity.GooglePlusActivity.onResume(GooglePlusActivity.java:96)
03-15 20:55:09.848: W/System.err(22572):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1241)
03-15 20:55:09.848: W/System.err(22572):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6063)
03-15 20:55:09.848: W/System.err(22572):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2947)
03-15 20:55:09.848: W/System.err(22572):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2989)
03-15 20:55:09.848: W/System.err(22572):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2372)
03-15 20:55:09.848: W/System.err(22572):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
03-15 20:55:09.848: W/System.err(22572):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
03-15 20:55:09.848: W/System.err(22572):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-15 20:55:09.848: W/System.err(22572):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
03-15 20:55:09.848: W/System.err(22572):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5274)
03-15 20:55:09.849: W/System.err(22572):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-15 20:55:09.849: W/System.err(22572):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
03-15 20:55:09.849: W/System.err(22572):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
03-15 20:55:09.849: W/System.err(22572):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is:

```
if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {           
    mSignInClicked = true;
    resolveSignInError();
}
```

The current flow you have looks like this:

- Connect GoogleAPIClient
- If GoogleAPIClient not connecting, mSignInClicked = true

You will then get: `onConnectionFailedCallback` where you check if `mSignInClicked == true` if so, try to resolve the error.

Change your googlePlusLogin to

```
public void googlePlusLogin() {
    mSignInClicked = true;
}
```

The root cause of this error is that you have used code which is mostly correct for a user interactive login, and tried to make it work on activity creation. The difference is purely time. If your googlePlusLogin was called by a human pressing a button (instead of onStart), it would probably be OK, as the GoogleApiClient would likely have completed the connection setup. By doing it as soon as the activity starts, you're pretty much guaranteeing that it wont be connected, at which case you are stuck with your code as it stands.

Comment: I did a check on the form onConnectionFailed ( ) ; putting a Toast '  if (!mIntentInProgress) {
   mConnectionResult = result;
   getProfileInformation();
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test Toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }'                                                                                           and I will return the toast when I press on the log in...

Comment: As a test, I would strip your code down - make it immediately resolve the error in onConnectionFailed and see what result you get.

Comment: anything, but I do not understand why creating a new project and copying the same class as the login is successful, maybe it will be the fact that the class is called with the Intent ? and therefore can not communicate with the MainActivity

Comment: Mainly because you're triggering directly AFAICS - with the button the class would load, wait, then have the button press, but here you are basically pressing the button as part of the activity loading process. Because sign-in is a background activity there is a bit of delay, which isn't visible if a user is involved, but is if its happening as part of the load process.

Comment: He 'd noticed this but do not know how to solve , it seems the only thing left to do is create a new layout.xml and login from that , but it's not what I want ...

Comment: If you've got updated code where you fix the race I mentioned in the original answer update your question with it, and I can take another look!

Comment: If you haven't changed it - move googlePlusLogin();
    getProfileInformation(); from the onStart to onConnection failed - replace the lines that say if (signedInUser){} with that.

Comment: I did as you say , and I get an error Toast...so nothing

Comment: This is logcat System.err(5997): java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient must be connected.

Comment: If you edit and paste your current code in to your question I can take a look but I can't really guess at whats going wrong currently!

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect. If it helps understanding, try drawing out the flow between the methods. Remember - the .connect call is not instant, it takes some unknown amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

It says you are not connected with mGoogleApiClient. Since you are not connected add mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() check there as well.

Port these lines
   `googlePlusLogin();
 getProfileInformation();`
to onConnected method.

You had to register your application in google console "credentials" part. So perhaps you are using different key to sign your application then the one you have added to google console.

Comment: If you are still getting same error as before that means you are calling mGoogleApiClient before onConnected somewhere else. Or is it that nothing is happening?

Comment: Did you add your app credentials with both production key and android debug key? As displayed here [Quick-start sample app for Android](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android)